# How do you translate "could have been" sentences?

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice, vocabulary, sentence-structure

For example, how do you translate this: "All his wife wanted was a peaceful life. When he returned from the war, their lives could have been peaceful, but the government situation at that time prevented it."

I have no idea how to say these kinds of "could have/would have" hypotheticals in Chinese.

Comment: There is a precondition that **if everything was like before**. If this precondition is satisfied, then they can live peacefully. But this precondition is broken because " the government situation at that time prevented it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'could have been' basically means “本来可以” while 'would have been' means “本来会”. For example

> He **could have been** there but there was an accident.
>
> 他**本(来)可以**到那里的，但是出了点意外。
>
> He **would have been** a doctor if he wasn't hurt.
>
> 如果他没受伤，他**本会**成为一名医生。

Generally, hypotheses in Chinese include the character “**本**”, like “本来”, “本会”,“本能够”,“本应该”,“本可以”,“本可能”.

Well, there are several mistakes in Kevman's translation.

1. “妻子”

> All his wife wanted was a peaceful life.

This should be

> 他的妻子只想要平静的生活。

'All his **wife** wanted' means “他的**妻子**只想要” rather than “他的**妻子们**”

2. “他们”

> their lives could have been peaceful

This should be

> 他们本可以平静地生活着

'their' means “他们的”, because it refers to the man and his wife.

When it refers to people including **male** and **female**, it should be translated into “他们的”. Work the same for 'they', 'them' and 'themselves'.

The rest is just as Kevman said.

---------------divide-----------

For Kevman's translation is not shown, I will type the whole translation below.

> All his wife wanted was a peaceful life. When he returned from the war, their lives **could have been** peaceful, but the government situation at that time prevented it.
>
> 他的妻子只希望过平静的生活。(但)在他从战场归来后，繁忙的政府公务没让他们过上**本(来)该有**的平静生活。

This translation is more natural but not formally same. That's why you see “本该有” rather than “本可以”。

One more thing, just as Jesse said, there is a precondition that if everything was like before.

Comment: You are right. I am confused at first and I forget the plural of wife is wives. :)

Comment: Kevman's translation is not shown at the moment, so this answer is a bit incomplete.

Comment: I'v updated the answer. Thank you for notifying me.